# Putting two elements in the same line

Tags: html, css

How to put the `<p>` and the `<h3>` tags in the same line ?
Now the `<p>` is above the `<h3>`

I want them on the same line but have different fonts so the H3 cannot go inside the P

```
<a href="/sharp/posts/{{ $day_qsts_3->id }}">
   <span>
        <p>{{$data->getcategory($data->id)}}</p>
        <h3 style="display: inline-block;">{{$day_qsts_3->title}}</h3>
   </span>
</a>
```

Comment: use `display:inline` for the `parent`.

Comment: span is inherently an inline element Abhyudai and you don't have valid HTML span should not contain headers or paragraphs https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element here is another note in the docs: **Most elements that are categorized as phrasing content can only contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content, not any flow content.**

Comment: Strongly agree with @04FS as i start using stack-overflow to help community of newbie's like am this step really heart a lot and kill the confidence level to ask question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

EDIT: Consider fixing your markup first. Below is one of the solutions using the provided HTML unchanged.

Maybe `display: flex` on the parent ? :) It will put the child elements in the same line

```css
span {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<a href="/sharp/posts/{{ $day_qsts_3->id }}">
   <span>
        <p>{{$data->getcategory($data->id)}}</p>
        <h3>{{$day_qsts_3->title}}</h3>
   </span>
</a>
```

Comment: this is poor practice to recommend invalid HTML markup. The permitted content for a span tag is only [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

Comment: Yes, You're right. I already edited the post to suggest fixing the markup first. When answering that question, I thought that the author is looking for CSS solution only without changing the HTML (which is wrong -  I agree)

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
p{
   display: inline-block;
}

h3{
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<a href="/sharp/posts/{{ $day_qsts_3->id }}">
        <p style="display: inline-block;">{{$data->getcategory($data->id)}}</p>
        <h3 style="display: inline-block;">{{$day_qsts_3->title}}</h3>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are lot of ways to achieve that. depends what exactly you want to achieve.

Easiest way would be as shown below.

```css
.text-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap/* if you want the text always to be in same line, remove this line of code.*/
}
```

```html
<a href="/sharp/posts/{{ $day_qsts_3->id }}">
  <span class="text-wrapper">
        <p>{{$data->getcategory($data->id)}}</p>
        <h3 style="display: inline-block;">{{$day_qsts_3->title}}</h3>
   </span>
</a>
```

Comment: this is poor practice to recommend invalid HTML. The permitted content model for a span tag is only [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element)

Comment: @soulshined I'm not recommending invalid HTML. The markup was provided by the user. I recommended a solution using same markup.